# Why I am getting reduce app bundle size warning despite installed bable import plugin in ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have next warning

```
index.js:8 You are using a whole package of antd, please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import to reduce app bundle size
```

but I have installed bable import plugin and .bebelrc settings

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-require",
    "babel-root-slash-import",
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
  ]

}
```